# Change where deleted emails go?

Tags: email

I have a gmail account setup on my phone (lumia 925) and I have noticed that when I delete an email using the mail app it places it into a newly created "Deleted Items" folder instead of the trash.  Is there a way to change where deleted emails go?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior for the mail app on Windows Phone 8.

As an workaround you can search for a Gmail client on the Store. An specific app should met more some aspects of the service better than a general one.

As a suggestion I recommend you take a look at [MetroMail](http://www.wpcentral.com/metromail-first-full-gmail-app-windows-phone).

I know it probably is not exactly what you want but a general purpose email client never will met all requirements of every single email service. For example it not provides option to chose aliases that is built-in in Outlook.com.

Comment: I tried metromail, I didn't like how you had to tap the email once to open it, presumably, in a webview, then tap it again to open any links.